# Warning: incompatible pointer type on updating code

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, mkmapview

I'm trying to get rid of some depricated code for creating an overlay in a MapView and now I'm facingh this warning:

Incompatible pointer types returning 'MKCircleRenderer *' from a function with result type 'MKOverlayView * _Nonnull'

I've read a lot of Q&A's on this matter but until now I was not able to figure it out. What's wrong with my code?

```
// Create overlay
-   (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{

MKCircleRenderer *circleView = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
circleView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8];
circleView.lineWidth = 1;
return circleView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error says that `circleView` is type of `MKCircleRenderer *` but your return type is `MKOverlayView *` . These types should be same.

```
-   (MKCircleRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{

MKCircleRenderer *circleView = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
circleView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8];
circleView.lineWidth = 1;
return circleView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a hint on how to do that? I don't have a lot of experience (sorry)

Comment: @A3O please give feedback, if it solves your problem

Comment: yes it did. I was AFK for a little while. I will accept your answer. Thank you very much!